# Tomcat and Intelij, tomcat doesn't seem to be used, instead intelij's port is used

Tags: html, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have downloaded tomcat, used start.sh and shutdown.sh to display the default localhost:8080 page that states that tomcat is working properly, no problem there. I added tomcat to intelij and i added the artifact that intelij recommended. But when running tomcat, i get no errors in server output, but i can't reach localhost:8080 (404 error), and i tried to run my html pages with tomcat but they seem to only work when tomcat uses the intelij port.

[tomcat configuration](https://i.gyazo.com/9020c28159d5e03e6a4db375e4b4996d.png)
[program structure](https://i.gyazo.com/e79c99c40e6ccfbb4a17aa19880d9f51.png)
[artifact](https://i.gyazo.com/1504bbbf1ba55c5749f188540a0a97cf.png)

when i click the browse icon of URL and select the html page, it automatically uses the port that Intelij is running on, and not through 8080. When i try to later reach my servlet through this html page, nothing happens, possibly because tomcat is never used?
the html page when accessed through `http://localhost:63342/Diatom/web/html/startrenewed.html` works fine.

How do i make intellij use the 8080 port of tomcat? Or if my problem lies in a different area, please support me in finding where the mistake really lies.

Comment: Can you hit the localhost 63342 application even when Intelij is closed?  I'm thinking this is running as a process somewhere else

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli localhost63342 gives no connection when intellij is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem after messing around with the artifact some more.
WEB-INF only contained classes and lib, I included both 'WEB-INF' directory contents and Diatom module: 'Web' facet resources. I think one of these isn't needed, but I'm too afraid to break it again by messing around with it, so I will leave it as it is for now.